# Difference between statement and line coverage in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, code-coverage

Can anyone explains me the difference between line coverage and statement coverage in jest.
When I ran my coverage report I got a different line coverage percentage compared to statement.
[image]

Comment: what is the unit coverage in this output? is this the number of lines covered in this repository which is 45.45 % here?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

if you have a line of code that says
`var x= 10; console.log(x);`
that's one line and 2 statements.

Statement coverage has each statement in the program been executed.

Line coverage has each executable line in the source file been executed.